# Featured articles list

Tags: wordpress, list, wordpress-featured-image

I'd like to display 10 articles from "featured" category. Only the first should have title and excerpt, the rest 9 only titles. How'd I do that?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I can display 10 posts with excerpts from the featured category:  get_posts('numberposts=10&category_name=featured') but not sure how to display first with excerpt and only the title for the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looping through the posts, just check if current `$post` in the loop is the first one in the return from the `get_posts` function:

```
<?php
    $featured = get_posts('numberposts=10&category_name=featured'); // Your original query

    foreach($featured as $post):
        $first = ($post == $featured[0]);
        setup_postdata( $post );

        if($first): ?>

        <div class="post main-featured">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php else: ?>

        <div class="post featured">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>

        <?php endif;        
    endforeach;
?>
```